# Clone of a woman writer

Tags: story-identification, clones

Someone told me about a book in which a woman writer cloned herself in order to educate her child to make her become a greater writer than herself.

Comment: ... This is really short on details. When did you read it? Where? What language? Any idea of what they might have been reading at the time?